# SQL when sum of supplies count reach to the demands count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to generate a query in SqlServer 2014 from two tables, have no relation with each other.

The first one represents the demands. And the second one represents the supplies for them.

```
Demands(
    [DemandId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TotalCount] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL)

Supplies(
    [SupplyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Count] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL)
```

For example, we have a demand with `(TotalCount = 1000, ItemCode = 1, Date = d1)`
and two Supplies in `(Date = d2, Count = 300, ItemCode = 1)` and `(Date = d3, Count = 700, ItemCode = 1)`
the demand finished in `d3 Date`, so I want a query to indicate when supplies have finished the demands.

consider the following data:

[image]

the result should be:

```
Item01 2020-01-07

Item02 2020-01-06
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Give actual example data for each table, and the exact example results you desire for that example data.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated.

Comment: @MatBailie updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple summary could be...

- treat a demand as a negative amount of supply
- combine the two datasets in to a single time series
- use a cumulative sum to see the net availability

Such as...

```
WITH
  NetContribution AS
(
  SELECT [ItemCode], [Date],  [Count]      FROM Supplies
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [ItemCode], [Date], -[TotalCount] FROM Demands
)
SELECT
  [ItemCode],
  [Date],
  [Count]       AS NetAvailabilityChange,
  SUM([Count])
    OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemCode]
              ORDER BY [Date],
                       [Count] DESC
         )
                AS NetAvailability
FROM
  NetContribution
```

While the NetAvailability is negative, Supply has not yet met Demand.  While it's positive, Supply has exceeded Demand.

***EDIT:*** In response to your question edit...

Just use the above query and add a `WHERE` clause...

```
WITH
  NetContribution AS
(
  SELECT [ItemCode], [Date],  [Count]      FROM Supplies
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [ItemCode], [Date], -[TotalCount] FROM Demands
),
  NetAvailability AS
(
  SELECT
    [ItemCode],
    [Date],
    [Count]       AS Delta,
    SUM([Count])
      OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemCode]
                ORDER BY [Date],
                         [Count] DESC
           )
                  AS Amount
  FROM
    NetContribution
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  NetAvailability
WHERE
  Amount >= 0
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but "over" is not supported in SQL 2014

Comment: @M.Khooryani - Are you sure about that?  I used it in 2008...

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of using `SUM() OVER()` to generate a cumulative sum, you *can* use a triangular join *(Join the current row on to all preceding rows)*, but on large data sets is nastily slow...

```
WITH
  NetContribution AS
(
  SELECT [ItemCode], [Date], SUM([Count]) AS [Count]
    FROM (
           SELECT [ItemCode], [Date],  [Count]      FROM Supplies
           UNION ALL
           SELECT [ItemCode], [Date], -[TotalCount] FROM Demands
         )
          combined
GROUP BY [ItemCode], [Date]
),
  NetAvailability AS
(
  SELECT
    a.[ItemCode],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Count]       AS Delta,
    SUM(b.[Count])  AS Amount
  FROM
    NetContribution AS a
  INNER JOIN
    NetContribution AS b
      ON  a.[ItemCode]  = b.[ItemCode]
      AND a.[Date]     >= b.[Date]
  GROUP BY
    a.[ItemCode],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Count]
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  NetAvailability
WHERE
  Amount >= 0
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=48660224fc63bcb2803f5a08b8b1311e

Comment: thanks but it has an issue, in the example, if I change the "Count" to 20 where "supplyId" is 2, it gives the wrong results.

Comment: @M.Khooryani - You really need to be a lot more specific.  What results does it give, what results should it give.  Edit and update your question.

Comment: @M.Khooryani - I've revised the answer to be more robust to changes in data and included a demonstration in the link *(which also demonstrates the `SUM() OVER ()` syntax does indeed work in SQL Server 2014...)*

Answer (score 1):

This is my source data

Demand :
'1', 'A', '1000', '2020-12-01'

'4', 'B', '2000', '2020-12-01'

Supply :
'2', 'A', '700', '2020-12-05' 
'3', 'A', '300', '2020-12-08' 
'5', 'B', '1000', '2020-12-05' 
'6', 'B', '1000','2020-12-08'

Performed the below query :

```
select a.itemcode, case when totaldemand - totalsupply = 0 then endsupplydate 
else null end enddate from </b> 
(
select 'demand' type,itemcode,sum(quantity) totaldemand,min(demanddate) as 
date from demand b group by type,itemcode ) b
inner join (
select 'supply' type,itemcode,sum(quantity) totalsupply,max(supplydate) as 
endsupplydate from supply group by type,itemcode) a
on a.itemcode = b.itemcode;
```

Output you will be getting :

ItemCode,DemandStart,SupplyEnd,QuantityLeft 
'A', '2020-12-08' 
'B', '2020-12-08'